# Custom Select tag like behaviour using bootstrap button and dropdown element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

```js
$('.btn-group').on('focus', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {

  $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');


  //Displays selected text on dropdown-toggle button
  $(this).closest(":has(button)").find('button').html('<div class="dropDownSelected">' + $(this).html() + '</div>' + '<span class="caret" style="float:right;"></span>');

});
```

```css
.btn-group,
.dropdown-menu {
  max-width: 150px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  white-space: normal!important;
  ;
}
.dropDownSelected {
  white-space: normal;
  margin-right: 22px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link which is of two lines or more</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
```

We have used Bootstrap's button-dropdown component to create a SELECT TAG like experience. User can click the dropdown and choose any option and the same value is instantly shown inside button (accessible via Mouse as well as keyboard)

**Step 1:** Click on single line option value inside dropdown.

**Step 2:** Now click on some multiple lines option value inside dropdown.

**Step 3:** Now once again click on some single line option value inside dropdown.

**Issue: After step 3 the dropdown list(i.e., ul) is not disappearing.**

Expected Result: After step 3 the dropdown list(i.e., ul) should disappear on every selection of options(both on mouse click and keyboard usage).

**Please ignore caret and design related minor bugs**

Comment: I have updated my answer with the complete working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why won't you close the list manually?

Replace this line:

```
$(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').find('li').removeClass('active');
```

With this:

```
$(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').parent().removeClass('open').end().find('li').removeClass('active');
```

This would be the end code:

```js
$('.btn-group').on('focus', '.dropdown-menu li', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');

   //Displays selected text on dropdown-toggle button
   $(this).closest(":has(button)").find('button').html('<div class="dropDownSelected">' + $(this).children('a').html() + '</div>' + '<span class="caret" style="float:right;"></span>');
}).on('click mouseup', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
   $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.btn-group,
.dropdown-menu {
  max-width: 150px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  white-space: normal!important;
  ;
}
.dropDownSelected {
  white-space: normal;
  margin-right: 22px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link which is of two lines or more</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: now it doesn't works with keyboard navigation! try accessing this via keyboard arrow keys. - or check mine one from question

Comment: @DeepakYadav - I changed the event from `focus` to `click` and I think it works. Please try again

Comment: :-D but, when you access it via keyboard, you'll notice that, the text inside button tag doesn't changes in real-time as you focus/move over the dropdown list. Check my question example.

Comment: @DeepakYadav - Added one more change. finger crossed :)

Answer (score 0):

Just alter the JS to either remove or hide the DOM.

For example:

```js
$('.btn-group').on('focus', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {

  $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');


  //Displays selected text on dropdown-toggle button
  $(this).closest(":has(button)").find('button').html('<div class="dropDownSelected">' + $(this).html() + '</div>' + '<span class="caret" style="float:right;"></span>');
  
 $('.dropdown-menu').hide()


});
```

```css
.btn-group,
.dropdown-menu {
  max-width: 150px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  white-space: normal!important;
  ;
}
.dropDownSelected {
  white-space: normal;
  margin-right: 22px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link which is of two lines or more</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Now if you run it, it's not a dropdown anymore. Then just style the button you created the way you want.

Comment: it doesn't opens the dropdown next time

Comment: @DeepakYadav isn't that the point? You said you don't want the ul

Comment: Check my example once again, as explained in STEPS. My user should be able to Click on button --> Choose an value from dropdown(like select tag) --> Dropdown should collapse after Value selection --> And should work again  (shouldn't stop)

Comment: @DeepakYadav ioh i see. in that case, you have to put the dropdown-toggle in the <ul>

Comment: @DeepakYadav Why not just use a <select> tag for all this?

Comment: you know - **Client Requirement** :'(